# Keyboard that can't be removed in Windows 8

Tags: keyboard, windows-8-preview, regional-settings

Somehow I ended up with four keyboards installed (English (United States), Japanese (Japan), Kannada, and Hindi. They are installed in the sense that the tray drop down displays these four, and when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> through my keyboards it cycles through them. The mysterious thing is that in the Languages Control Panel, only the first two are shown, so I am stuck as to how to remove the last two.

In the past, I may have installed and removed the Kannada and Hindi keyboards. What I did recently was to install the English (India) keyboard, as a way to get the ability to input the rupee symbol with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>. That English (India) keyboard *did* show up in the Languages Control Panel and allow itself to be removed. It almost seems like installing that keyboard somehow activate hidden registry settings left over from back when I had Kannada and Hindi installed.

In any case, any ideas about how to remove these keyboards which don't appear in the Language Control Panel?

Comment: This problem was solved by uninstalling "Microsoft Indic Language Input Tool for Kannada" and "Microsoft Indic Language Input Tool for Hindi" via the Control Panel/Add and Remove Programs, then rebooting.